# JAVA - Out Of Memory - Voxel World Generation

Tags: java, memory, out

Currently I have this for code and my game either uses way to much memory when generating (over a GB) or if I set it low, it will give a

WORLD_SIZE_X & WORLD_SIZE_Z = 256;

WORLD_SIZE_Y = 128;

Does anyone know how I could improve this so it doesn't use so much RAM?

Thanks! :)

```
public void generate() {
    for(int xP = 0; xP < WORLD_SIZE_X; xP++) {
        for(int zP = 0; zP < WORLD_SIZE_Z; zP++) {
            for(int yP = 0; yP < WORLD_SIZE_Y; yP++) {

                try {
                    blocks[xP][yP][zP] = new BlockAir();

                    if(yP == 4) {
                        blocks[xP][yP][zP] = new BlockGrass();
                    }
                    if(yP < 4) {
                        blocks[xP][yP][zP] = new BlockDirt();
                    }
                    if(yP == 0) {
                        blocks[xP][yP][zP] = new BlockUnbreakable();
                    }
                } catch(Exception e) {}
            }


            //Tree Generation :D
            Random rX = new Random();
            Random rZ = new Random();
            if(rX.nextInt(WORLD_SIZE_X) < WORLD_SIZE_X / 6 && rZ.nextInt(WORLD_SIZE_Z) < WORLD_SIZE_Z / 6) {
                for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                    blocks[xP][5 + j][zP] = new BlockLog();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    generated = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cause you just give small piece of code, I can give you two suggestions:

1. compact the object size. Seems very stupid but very easy to do. Just imagine you have thousands of objects in your memory. If everyone can be compacted half size, you can save half memory :).
2. Just assign the value to array when you need it. Sometime it is not work if you need really need a assigned array. So just assign values to elements in array as LESS as you can. If you can show me more code, I can help you more.

Answer (score 1):

Delay object creation until you really need to access one of these voxels. You can write a method (I'm assuming Block as the common subclass of all the Block classes):

```
Block getBlockAt( int x, int y, int z )
```

using code similar what you have in your threefold loop, plus using a hash map `Map<Integer,Block>` for storing the random stuff, e.g. trees: from x, y and z compute an integer `(x*128 + y)*256 + z` and use this as the key.

Also, consider that for all "air", "log", "dirt" blocks you may not need a separate object unless something must be changed at a certain block. Until then, share a single object of a kind.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the problem is in this method? Unless Block objects are really big, 256*256*128 ~= 8M objects should not require 1 GB ...

That said, if the blocks do not hold state, it would be more memory efficient to use an enum (or even a byte instead), as we would not need a separate object for each block:

```
enum Block {
    air, grass, dirt, log, unbreakable;
}

Block[][][] map = ...
```